# $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\big(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^3+kn}-\frac{1}{3}\big)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, solution-verification

calculate $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k^2}{n^3+kn}-\dfrac{1}{3}\right).$$
I got it $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k^2}{n^3+kn}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(\frac{k}{n})^2}{1+\frac{k}{n^2}}.$$
Use Squeeze theorem we have
$$\frac{1}{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\frac{k}{n})^2<\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(\frac{k}{n})^2}{1+\frac{k}{n^2}}<\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\frac{k}{n})^2$$
So $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k^2}{n^3+kn}=\int_0^1x^2\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{3}.$$
Use $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\left(\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm{d}x-\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)=\frac{f(0)-f(1)}{2}.$$
Hence $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k^2}{n^3+kn}-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)=\frac{1}{2}.$$
If our method is correct, is there any other way to solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: Good question. And nice attempt (even though final answer is not correct). +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach can be fixed easily. You have to evaluate the limit of $n(S_n-(1/3))$ and you have also shown that $$\frac{n} {n+1}R_n<S_n<R_n$$ where $R_n=n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k/n)$ is the Riemann sum for $f(x) =x^2$ over $[0,1]$.

It is well known that $$n\left(R_n-\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx\right)\to\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\tag{1}$$ Our job is complete if we can evaluate the limit $L$ of $n(S_n-R_n)$ and our desired limit will be $L+1/2$.

But $$n(S_n-R_n) =-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k/n^2}{1+(k/n^2)}\cdot\frac{k^2}{n^2}$$ The sum on right can again be squeezed (as in question) to get the limit $L=-1/4$. The desired limit is thus $1/4$.

**Moral of the Story**: Do not deviate even an iota from the hypotheses and conclusion of a theorem. If you do that try to do further analysis and prove the desired changes. The result (equation $(1)$ above) you use deals with a specific Riemann sum and that can't be replaced by any similar looking sum (even having same limit).

Comment: Oh，I finally saw a proof that I like, thank you

Comment: @夜愿1998: glad to be of help!

Answer (score 3):

There is another using generalized haromonic numbers since
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k^2}{n^3+kn}=n^3 \left(H_{n^2+n}-H_{n^2}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \left(-2 n^2+n+1\right)$$
$$S_n=-\dfrac{1}{3}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k^2}{n^3+kn}=\frac{1}{6} \left(-6 n^2+3n+1\right)+n^3 \left(H_{n^2+n}-H_{n^2}\right)$$ Using asymptotics
$$S_n=\frac{1}{4 n}-\frac{2}{15 n^2}+\frac{1}{12 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
$$nS_n=\frac{1}{4 }-\frac{2}{15 n}+\frac{1}{12 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ and we do not agree !

Try with $n=10$; the exact value is
$$10 S_{10}=10 \times \frac{140325051799081}{5909102214621606}\sim 0.237473$$ while the approximation gives $\frac{19}{80} \sim 0.237500$.

Comment: thank you,so is my answer wrong?

Comment: @夜愿1998. It seems that your answer is not correct.

Comment: thank you,I want to know which step is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Although $\sum\frac{k^2}{n^3+kn}$ and $\sum\frac{k^2}{n^3}$ have the same limit, they differ to $O(1/n)$. So when they are multiplied by $n$, they give different limits

Comment: Thank you. How can I improve my calculation

Comment: Perhaps multiply top and bottom by $n^2-k$ because the new denominator is between $n^5$ and $n^5-n^3$

Answer (score 1):

In fact you are very close to the right answer. I would suggest you check Euler - Maclaurin formula first - plus, not minus in the second term, though it does not change the result that you got $(+\frac{1}{2})$: $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^nf(\frac{k}{n})=n\int_1^nf(t)dt+\frac{1}{2}\left(f(\frac{1}{n})+f(1)\right)+\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n})^{k-1}\frac{B_k}{k!}\left(f^{(k-1)}(1)-f^{(k-1)}(\frac{1}{n})\right)$$
Next, the integral in fact is $$n\int_0^1\frac{t^2}{1+\frac{1}{n}t}dt=n\int_0^1t^2dt-\int_0^1t^3dt+O(\frac{1}{n})$$ the second term here gives you additionally $-\frac{1}{4}$.

All together,
$$ \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: I have a question. Is my asymptotic formula not precise enough?

Comment: It is precise (if you put the plus instead of minus in the second term), but you used only two first terms of it in your calculations (which are enough to solve this problem). In fact there are other terms (which decline as powers of $\frac{1}{n}$);$B_k$ means Bernoulli coefficients.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand you. Which equation do you mean?

Comment: and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(\frac{k}{n})^2}{1+\frac{k}{n^2}}$ can be $\int_0^1\frac{t^2}{1+\frac{1}{n}t}dt$?

Comment: I mean the approximation of the sum which you use: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\left(\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm{d}x-\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)=\frac{f(0)-f(1)}{2}$

Comment: I would recommend you make calculations with the finite $n$ and take take limit $n\to{\infty}$ only at the end. In fact $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k^2}{n^3+kn}-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)$ has an asymptotic (at $n\to\infty)  \sim{n(3-3)}+n\frac{1}{4n}+nO(\frac{1}{n^2})$

Comment: thank you ,Can you tell me a little bit about the asymptotic formula

Comment: I would recommend a general information.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula Basically, for usage in the calculation this is enough. It is not difficult to derive the formula - but you have to know how bernoulli coefficients (in fact, these are just figures) are obtained.

Comment: thank you ,In this case, $f (x)$ you take is $\frac{x^2}{1+\frac{1}{n}x}$?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Make integration first (decomposing $f(x)$ in powers of $\frac{1}{n} $, cancel the diverging terms ($3n-3n$) and only then take a limit $n\to\infty$

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: It's my pleasure. Good luck :)